# Remove special character from string only if is not inside word

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all special characters from string but only if is not inside a word.

Special characters: `<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*'`

Example:

```
String str = "//won't won't wo/'n't wont wont'."
str.replaceAll(,"") // "won't won't won't wont wont"
```

Anyone know how to reach this through regex ?

Comment: What is a "special character"? You need to define that by providing a list of the characters you mean or, if appropriate, define a "special character as any character other than a word character, that is, any character other than a letter, digit or underscore. Also, you say you want to replace certain characters but you don't say what the replacement is.

Comment: i want to replace all of this characters: <>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*' and replace to empty string ""

Comment: If you do not wish to replace two or more contiguous special characters within a word I don't think you'll be able to do that with a simple regular expression. The problem is that that requires a variable-length negative lookbehind, which I do not believe is supported by Java.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to remove `()+-[]_\``?

Comment: Neither the selected answer nor any of the others deal with `wo/'n't` as you'd like, so you may wish to remove that from your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This RegEx:

`(?<!\w)\W+|\W+(?!\w)`

Matches either of two alternate RegEx. `(1|2)`

1. Any special character (non word character: `\W`) that is not preceded by a word character (`\w`)
2. Any special character that is not followed by a word character.

This works because if either is matched the special character must not be in a word

"is preceded": positive lookbehind.  `(?<=y)X`: X is preceded by y
"is not preceded": negative lookbehind.  `(?<!y)X`: X is not preceded by y
"is followed by": positive lookahead.  `X(?=y)`: X is followed by y
"is not followed by": negative lookahead.  `X(?!y)`: X is not followed by y.

You should replace the `\W` with your set of special characters (appropriately escaped)

One thing to note with this solution is that it does not depend on the existence of white space.

Comment: Thanks for logical clarify !

Comment: @CarySwoveland I considered only using the two alternates, but I wasn't 100% sure about how end of line and beginning of line would be treated.  `\w` is arguably preferable to the character range with case-insensitivity, and I decided to use `\W` to make the construction of the RegEx cleaner.

Comment: So close, but that removes spaces too, not just special characters, if there is a special character next to the space, e.g. `wo/'n't, wont` becomes `won'twont`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<![a-z])[<>{}"\/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*']|[<>{}"\/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*'](?![a-z])
```

with the case-insensitive flag set (`/i`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rc6fZG/2/)

Java's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<![a-z])                  # match a letter in a
                            # negative lookbehind
[<>{}"\/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*']  # match a special character
|
[<>{}"\/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*']  # match a special character
(?![a-z])                   # match a letter in a
                            # negative lookahead
```

Comment: Question listed special characters as ``<>{}\"/|;:.,~!?@#$%^=&*'`` so why did you remove ``\`` and why are you escaping ``/``? --- Also, what about input `I'm`? You're removing the `'` since you don't check uppercase letters.

Comment: @Andreas, I removed the backslash  because `"` need not be escaped. I escaped `/` because that is required. I am checking uppercase letters, as I said in my answer and show in the link.

Comment: It is true that `"` does not need to be escaped, but what makes you think the ``\`` before `"` was an attempt to escape? It is just a list of special characters. It is not a quoted text, where `"` needs escaping. --- `/` does not need escaping in regex. *Some* languages, which use `/.../` around a regex as a regex literal syntax, require `/` to be escaped. **Java** is not one of those languages. --- Question code uses `replaceAll()`, and you cannot set regex flags outside the regex in that call, so "with the case-insensitive flag set (/i)" is meaningless (for **Java**).

Comment: I cannot count the number of times I've seen `"` escaped in a regex, so I assumed that was the case here. If a backslash is meant to be a "special character", add an escaped backslash. `(/i)` may be meaningless for Java (I'll take your word for that), but I'd be surprised if any readers proficient in Java don't know what I meant by "the case-insensitive flag set".

Comment: *"add an escaped backslash"* Sure, unless it's a **plain text** list of special characters, where there is no such thing as "escaping", which for all we know, is what's in the question, since the question doesn't say otherwise. --- *"readers proficient in Java"* is besides the point. To specify the case-insensitive flag set in a regex, the reader would need to be proficient in **regex**. The question doesn't read like someone who is that proficient in regex. Since flags cannot be specified *separately* when using `replaceAll()`, how would you do it?